# Training ARIMA to forecast the trend

Tags: python, arima

I'm trying to forecast a trend using ARIMA. Unfortunately the output I get is far different from the expected one (behaviour for training and testing data is very similiar) and indicates as if the whole training data set was... useless?

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).to_period('D')

#data from 1/1/2016 to 31/12/2018
train = df.loc[:'2018-12-31']
test = df.loc['2019-01-01':]

model = auto_arima(train, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                   max_p=3, max_q=3, m=7,
                   start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                   d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                   error_action='ignore',
                   suppress_warnings=True,
                   stepwise=True)

model.aic()
model.fit(train)
ffforecast = model.predict(n_periods=len(test))
ffforecast = pd.DataFrame(fforecast,
                               index=test.index,
                               columns=['prediction'])
pd.concat([test, fforecast], axis=1).plot()
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

full code: https://pastebin.com/huer62cM

csv: https://filebin.net/rlvm3hrjetlovd64/newbikes6years.csv?t=nt3slw3y

Comment: There really isn’t enough information here, can you at least narrow down the issue?

Comment: Ok, so on the vertical axis there is an amount of trips per day. Why would a model predict a negative number? I mean, doesn't it indicate that there's something wrong? What's more is this strange shape of the curve, and the slope of the mean value. It seems to be totally ignoring the behaviour of the trend (blue line). To me this prediction doesn't fit at all in here.

Comment: Alright, but without the ability to run your program I don't know how much people can do to help.

Comment: Shall I post the .csv I'm working on?

Comment: That's probably a good place to start, alongside your code.

Comment: there you go:full code: https://pastebin.com/huer62cM csv: https://filebin.net/rlvm3hrjetlovd64/newbikes6years.csv?t=nt3slw3y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a bad set of parameters for your model.  It looks like you copy/pasted an example from a different data set and it's not working for you.

I would suggest something like:

```
model = auto_arima(train, error_action='ignore', trace=True, suppress_warnings=True,seasonal=True, maxiter=10, m=7)
```

Based on the output of this, you can go back and refine the parameters once you read up on them and learn what they do.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't specify the exact values of the parameters, just starting values. Also tried your approach, it improves the output a bit, but I'd thought that `auto_arima` is mostly like set-and-forget style, so that the parameters would be obtained over the training process.

Comment: You set start and max, which isn't a good idea until you know what that does.